# Post meta to custom field with multiple rows! - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm using the houzez theme and trying to develop a plugin to post from an API to a "property" post. "Property" is a custom post and one custom field (`additional_feature`) has multiple rows.

When I get the value from `additional_feature` using `get_post_meta()` in a sample post with the fields already filled we get:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fave_additional_feature_title] => aaa 
[fave_additional_feature_value] => 234 ) [1] => Array ( 
[fave_additional_feature_title] => bbb [fave_additional_feature_value] => 567 
) [2] => Array ( [fave_additional_feature_title] => ccc 
[fave_additional_feature_value] => 890 ) ) )
```

So, the custom field `additional_feature` has some more fields inside!! When I use `update_post_meta` it doesn't work. I tried setting up an array to pass the data exactly as the sample array looks like when called trough `get_post_meta()`. However, it doesn't work.

Any idea of how to update `additional_feature`?

Comment: I think you need to provide the exact code you are using and the exact result you are getting and say exactly what is wrong with that result. 'However, it doesn't work.' - really doesn't provide any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

*To output repeater meta (Is used - ACF custom field repeater).

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID); //Get all post meta per one request
$repeater_count = $meta["additional_feature"][0]; //Count of iteration

for ($i=0; $i<$repeater_count; $i++) {
 $feature_title = 'additional_feature_'.$i.'_title';
 echo $meta[$feature_title][0]; //Output repeater meta
}
```

*To update repeater meta (Use ACF custom field repeater). Update on save post.

**You can change the code for your needs**

**!!!Generate the working code better on the test site, because with erroneous names of the user fields, when saving the post, new fields will be created in the database table - post_meta.**

Add to functions.php

```
add_filter('acf/save_post', 'main_meta_filter', 20);
function main_meta_filter($post_id) {

    if ( $post_id != 7 ) //You can use post type if you need
        return;

//Repeater
$number_rows = get_post_meta( $post_id, "additional_feature" );//Count of iteration
 for ($i=0; $i<$number_rows[0]; $i++) {
  $key = 'additional_feature_'.$i.'_title';
//To get old value use $old_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, false);
//and output use $old_value[0]
  $new_value = 1;//You custom value
  update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $new_value);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something weird happened. I re-tried a method that didn't work but I had no more ideas. I used the following code:

```
$data = array(
   array(     
        'fave_additional_feature_title' => 'Ax',
        'fave_additional_feature_value' => 111,
   ),
);

update_post_meta($postid, 'additional_features', $data);
```

It worked this time. Very weird and I dont know how it didn't work before and now it works. However, now I can update the custom field.